# Remove element from list if it satisfies a condition defined from a separate list - Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists of equal length:

```
Offset = [-0.0002, -0.0004, -0.0004, -0.006, -0.0006, -0.0006, -0.0066, -0.0007, -0.0007, -0.0008]

Ratio = [0.0641, 0.152, 0.254, 0.246,  0.3197,  0.3249, 2.8795,  0.4286,  0.5191, 0.5712]
```

What i would like to do is to create a list whose elements originate from Offset provided that the corresponding element in Ratio is less than `2.5`. So for the two lists above, the 6th element in Ratio is greater than `2.5`, and i want to then delete the 6th element in Offset and return all other elements.

I've tried to do a list comprehension, my attempt is:

```
Data = [x for n in Ratio[n] for x in Offset if Ratio[n] < 2.5]
```

However this produces the error 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable', which from reading  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862459/numpy-float64-object-is-not-iterable) i can see why i get the error, but I'm not sure how to make the list comprehension work.

This for loop seems to be on the right tracks, but a) i would prefer a list comprehension
and b) I don't think you can delete elements in a list whilst iterating over it.

```
for n in range(len(Ratio)):

  if Ratio[n] < 2.5:
    #Keep the element Offset[n]
  else:
    #Delete the element Offset[n]
```

Comment: Just wanted to add something that might interest you. In Python, you CAN delete elements from a list while iterating over it. You just have to iterate BACKWARDS so that the list-shift does not affect your future path. That will avoid any out-of-bounds errors with list subscripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will produce the list you seek. The key is to use `zip` (or `izip` if you prefer) when you have lists with corresponding elements.

```
[offset for offset, ratio in zip(Offset, Ratio) if ratio < 2.5]
```

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered that when I ran the test.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds from the error message

```
 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable'
```

that `Ratio` is a numpy array. If both `Offset` and `Ratio` are NumPy arrays, then you can form the array you desire with

```
Offset[Ratio < 2.5]
```

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: Ratio = np.array([0.0641, 0.152, 0.254, 0.246,  0.3197,  0.3249, 2.8795,  0.4286,  0.5191, 0.5712])

In [3]: Offset = np.array([-0.0002, -0.0004, -0.0004, -0.006, -0.0006, -0.0006, -0.0066, -0.0007, -0.0007, -0.0008])

In [7]: Offset[Ratio < 2.5]
Out[7]: 
array([-0.0002, -0.0004, -0.0004, -0.006 , -0.0006, -0.0006, -0.0007,
       -0.0007, -0.0008])
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet this is the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

Your original list comprehension can be made to work using `enumerate`.

```
Data = [x for (i, x) in enumerate(Offset) if Ratio[i] < 2.5]
```

Which proves faster than `zip` but slower than `izip` in Python 2.7:

```
from time import time
from itertools import izip

Offset = [-0.0002, -0.0004, -0.0004, -0.006, -0.0006, -0.0006, -0.0066, -0.0007, -0.0007, -0.0008]
Ratio = [0.0641, 0.152, 0.254, 0.246,  0.3197,  0.3249, 2.8795,  0.4286,  0.5191, 0.5712]

def _enumerate():
    return [x for (i, x) in enumerate(Offset) if Ratio[i] < 2.5]

def _zip():
    return [offset for offset, ratio in zip(Offset, Ratio) if ratio < 2.5]

def _izip():
    return [offset for offset, ratio in izip(Offset, Ratio) if ratio < 2.5]

assert _enumerate() == _zip() == _izip()

for f in (_enumerate, _zip, _izip):
    start = time()
    for i in range(10000):
        f()
    print '%s: %s' % (time() - start, f.func_name)
```

Output:

```
0.0142180919647: _enumerate
0.0157129764557: _zip
0.0130951404572: _izip
```

Comment: In Python 3, `zip` returns an iterable and is faster than using `enumerate`.  In Python 2, where `zip` returns a list, use `itertools.izip` for maximum efficiency.

Comment: Good to know. I tested using Python 2.7.3. Thanks!