# Setting Cross Validation parameter in Grid Search

Tags: python, numpy, random-forest, grid-search

I am trying to set a RandomForestClassification inside a GridSearch

```
rfc_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 5, max_depth = 3 )

gs = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = rfc_model,
                             param_grid = {'n_estimators': [i for i in range(1,52,10)],
                                          "max_depth": [3, 5],
                                          "bootstrap": [True, False],
                                          "criterion": ["gini"]},
                             cv = cross_val_score(rfc_model,X, y, scoring='roc_auc'))

gs.fit(X, y)
gs.grid_scores_
print gs.best_estimator
print gs.best_score_
```

I get the error

`TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`

Obviously I am learning, so any comments are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16865814/7714663 this might help you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem, I was using the wrong method(Is it alright to call it method?) for Cross Validation, below the solution:

```
gs = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = model,
                             param_grid = {'n_estimators': [i for i in range(1,52,10)],
                                          "max_depth": [3, 5],
                                          "bootstrap": [True, False],
                                          "criterion": ["gini"]},
                             cv = cross_validation.KFold(n=len(X), n_folds=10), scoring='roc_auc')
```