# 'numpy.float64' is not iterable for scipy function centre of mass

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I've been trying to calculate the centre of mass of precipitation fields from my observation data (.nc format) but I keep getting an error message: `"TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"`

I've managed to convert my **netcdf** file from `.nc` into a xarray dataset and then extract the values to give a (1, 90, 180) array that I then converted into (90, 180) for other functionalities. I then tried calculating centre of mass for the array but it keeps giving me an error message.

```
from scipy import ndimage

ncobsdata = Dataset('/home/data/20180380293.nc', mode = 'r')
obsdata = xr.open_dataset(xr.backends.NetCDF4DataStore(ncobsdata))
obs = obsdata.rain_total #shape = (1, 90, 180)

obsv = np.squeeze(obs) #I had to do this step to make it (90, 180)

CoM_obsv = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(obsv)
```

I expect to get the centre of mass result but I just keep getting the error message:

```
File "_____.py", line 10, in <module>
   CoM_obsv = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(obsv)
File "________/scipy/ndimage/measurements.py", line 1289, in center_of_mass
   return [tuple(v) for v in numpy.array(results).T]
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Which line in your traceback gives the `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`? This usually means you're trying to iterate through a list/iterable but the object you've passed in appears to be a single float64.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['numpy.float64' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862459/numpy-float64-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Looks like your `obsv` variable may not be the 2D array you expect. Can you do a quick print check: `print(obsv)` or `print(obsv.shape)` to see what it is?

Comment: @PeptideWitch `print(obsv.shape)` gives the result `(180, 270)`. When I do `print (obsv)`, it says: `<xarray.DataArray  'rain_total'  (lat: 180, lon: 270)>` with `dtype=float32`
I did originally say (90, 180) but I didn't think that this would give me the error message

Comment: Ok having a look at the Xarray documentation, it may by the case that you'll need to access the values of the DataArray object. So perhaps try: `CoM_obsv = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(obsv.values)`

Comment: @PeptideWitch that works, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. Check out http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html for a full list of all the stuff you can do with these xarray objects - it may come in handy in the future when stuff like this pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what was happening here was that both the `obs` and `obsv` variables are stored as xarray.DataArrays - this class is a wrapper around regular numpy arrays. To access the underlying np.ndarray, you will need to call the values from the object:

`CoM_obsv = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(obsv.values)`

Note that you didn't need to do this for `obsv = np.squeeze(obs) #I had to do this step to make it (90, 180)` because there is already a squeeze method available for xarray.DataArrays.